# Can someone tell me why .checked function isn't firing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple .checked function in javascript to verify a checkbox and change styles in the dom and even console.log. Nothing is firing when it is checked and I can't figure out why. What am I missing?

```
function validate() {
  if (document.querySelector(".slide-footer").checked) {
    document.querySelector(".footer-container").style.bottom = -12 + "rem";
    console.log("hello");
  }
}

validate();
```

```
<footer class="footer">
      <ul class="footer-container">
        <input id="checkbox-slider" type="checkbox" class="slide-footer"></input>
        <label for="checkbox-slider" class="checkbox-btn"></label>
        <div class="order-container">
          <p class="order1">Order</p>
          <div class="price-cont">
            <span class="dollar-amnt">$</span><span class="info">0</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Works just fine here, when `validate` runs, if the checkbox is checked, `hello` gets logged

Comment: Because you fire that function exactly once right after you've defined it, and it does the check right then once, and the box isn't checked yet, and then the function never fires again?

Comment: If you want your code to react to a click on the checkbox, you need to add an event listener to it.

Comment: Side-note: The `<input>` tag [should _not_ have an end tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Technical_summary).

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously missing an event listener that listens to your clicks

If you want to listen to some events like, mouse click, scroll, keypress etc. then you need an event listener.

In this case you could use an `click` listener that listens only to clicks or better an `change` event listener that listens to changes.

```js
function validate() {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    document.querySelector(".footer-container").style.bottom = -12 + "rem";
    console.log("hello");
  }
}

let checkbox = document.querySelector(".slide-footer")

checkbox.addEventListener("change", validate);
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
      <ul class="footer-container">
        <input id="checkbox-slider" type="checkbox" class="slide-footer"></input>
        <label for="checkbox-slider" class="checkbox-btn"></label>
        <div class="order-container">
          <p class="order1">Order</p>
          <div class="price-cont">
            <span class="dollar-amnt">$</span><span class="info">0</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </footer>
```